# Add hint text to programatically added TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint, textinputlayout

Hi I have created custom component for TextInputLayout. I want to set hint text to TextInputLayout. I am adding custom class which extends TextInputLayout into my root layout. I tried it in following way:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
android:theme="@style/editTextSelectedTheme"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/form_et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

```
    public class FormEditText extends TextInputLayout
{
    TextInputLayout view;
    public FormEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = (TextInputLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_edit_text, this, true);
        initUI();
    }

    public FormEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FormEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

And finally in my fragment:

```
FormEditText gadgetName = new FormEditText(getContext());
gadgetName.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.gadget_name_hint));
formContainer.addView(gadgetName);
```

Above code adds new TextInputLayout in my view but not adding hint text for it. Am I doing anything wrong? Need Some help. Thank you.

I did few changes as per comment below.

```
public class FormEditText extends LinearLayout

view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_edit_text, this, true);
```

Now it si showing hint text as per required.But now it is not showing my edit text value.It is not taking any input value.

Comment: You've got two `TextInputLayout`s there; the inflated one nested inside your custom one.

Comment: Yes got it.It is working. Make FormEditText  to extend LinearLayout.

Comment: @MikeM. I did changes as your suggestion. It is now showing hint text but now it is not taking any input value. It is not taking any keyboard input text.

Comment: I didn't really suggest anything. I just pointed out the crux of your problem. Anyway, what exactly do you mean by "It is not taking any input value."? Can you just not see the text? Can you see the cursor? Does the hint float on focus? What happens if you set some text programmatically? Also, do you really need a custom `View` class for this? Can't you just inflate that layout as needed, and add that to `formContainer`?

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you for kind help and quick replay. I am able to see cursor. Hint text also float on focus.But I can not see any text inside it once I type. I need this as custom class coz I need to generate some form dynamically. So instead of creating xml layout I would prefere dynamically generated forms. I have also added other code inside this custom class like validations and error.But that doesn't have impact while rendering layout.

Comment: If the cursor moves when you type, then it sounds like the text color is blending in with the background color. Try changing one of those on the `EditText`.

Comment: @MikeM. I tried that as well. I changed background color. but it is not actually taking any text input value.

Comment: I got my problem @MikeM. Inside my custom class I have set maxLength as -1. Coz of that it is causing this issue. Fixed now. Thank you for your support.